# Ionic v4 `menuController.enable` method not working on first page loaded

Tags: ionic4

I use a sidemenu project with ionic v4-beta3

I want to disable sidemenu on some pages, `/login` for example.

It's working properly when i load `/home` page first then i navigate to `/login` page. Sidemenu desapear as expected.

**When i reload my application on `/login` page, menu is not disabled.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private menuController: MenuController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
    this.menuController.enable(false);
  }

  ionViewDidLeave() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLeave');
    this.menuController.enable(true);
  }

}
```

---

If a use a setTimeout of 100 or 200 ms to call `enable` method, side menu desapears but it's not very clean...

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewWillEnter');
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        this.menuController.enable(false);
    }, 100);
}
```

---

Another work-around is to show `ion-menu` when `window.location.pathName`is not equal to `/login` with a `*ngIf` directive. It's working but i find this not very clean too...

---

Ionic Infos

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.1 
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.3
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.4
   @angular/cli               : 6.1.4
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.6
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.5
```

Comment: This is not resolved with Ionic 4.0.0-beta.5

Comment: Not yet resolved

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be resolved in 4.0.0-beta.12 with the following:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.menuController.enable(false);
}

ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.menuController.enable(true);
}
```

Comment: Not resolved in 4.0.0-beta.12.

Still have same behaviour. Menu is present when reloading app on /login page. Menu is hid when i navigate from /home to /login.

Comment: for me it got fixed with 4.0.0-beta.17

Comment: any solution? I am using ionic 5 and I have the same problem

Comment: @maroodb Check this option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64364344/7242535

Answer (score 1):

The `MenuController.enable()` method is asynchronous.

You can create a Guest/Authenticated guard and enable it there, and then use it in pages using the `canActivate` route parameter in your pages. Then, when your page loads, the menu will be configured properly. For example, for authenticated guard:

```ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private menuController: MenuController) {}

  async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    const isAuthenticated = true; // Adjust where you get this value
    await this.menuController.enable(isAuthenticated);

    return isAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

This will work for Ionic4/5.

> You should use `menuId` property in your `<ion-menu/>` components for fine-tune identity and be able to use multiple menus. Then you can call `.enable(isAuthenticated, menuId);`

Comment: nice solution. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented the above code and its better that before. However, I can still see the menu flicker once the page is loaded. Looks like it itsn't actually disabled before the view is loaded. Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: Try setting `disabled` by default to the `ion-menu` HTML (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu#properties), so you can enable it only in guards. Also, you may need a Guardian for guests routes.